# Easiest way to execute specific parallel task?

Tags: python, parallel-processing

We got a huge binary file, around 1TB. Now we want to parse it - iterate over it in chunks and extract some data from every chunk. The file is huge and we'd really like to avoid splitting it or copying it in any way, because it will consume even more HDD space.

Now we simply read it chunk-by-chunk and extract the data. Simple but not parallel. And it can't be parallelized 'in 2 lines of code' because we'd like to avoid copying objects across multiple processes (we don't have a lot of RAM). So basically we'd like to execute, let's say, 10 parser instances that would get access to the same memory object, at the same machine. Yep there are another ways to go, including map-reducing or something like that, but I want to simplify the things and stay close to the simplest method I described in the first sentence of this paragraph. Well I sure can remember offsets, run multiple processes (each will read the file starting from its own offset) etc., but maybe there's a tiny lib that makes it automagically? The task is really simple and common, just any log parsing is the same kind of task... Simplicity, speed, minimal memory consumption - that's just all I need... No monster hadoop clusters, no long blocks of code to write, no freezes and overheads.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So everything here should require no work on your part, not consume more RAM, not consume more disk space, impose no other overheads, never freeze, and give you a nice speedup.  You only forgot to ask that it deposit money to your bank account every 5 machine cycles too ;-)

Seriously, if it really *were* as simple as you assume it must be, nobody would *bother* to write a library for it.  Who would bother to download it?  If it's that easy, they could write it themselves in their sleep, and not have to hassle with trying to make sense of the documentation the library author probably didn't bother to write *because* it's so trivial.

That said, what's wrong with this approach?

```
def your_func(f, size):
    # Process `size` bytes beginning at the
    # current position in file object `f`,
    # which is open for reading in binary mode.

    # Your processing code goes here, presumably
    # containing one or more instances of
    #     f.read(SOME_NUMBER_OF_BYTES)

# All the rest is machinery to support multiprocessing.
def worker(path, offset, size):
    # Open the file, seek() to the correct offset,
    # invoke the user's processing code, and
    # return the passed-in offset & size for reporting.
    with open(path, "rb") as f:
        f.seek(offset)
        your_func(f, size)
    return (offset, size)

def progress_reporter(args):
    # A callback to report progress.  Optional.
    offset, size = args
    print "finished {:,} bytes at offset {:,}".format(size, offset)

def parallel_chunk(path, chunksize, ncpus=None):
    import os.path
    import multiprocessing

    p = multiprocessing.Pool(ncpus)  # None means all available
    full, leftover = divmod(os.path.getsize(path), chunksize)
    for i in range(full):
        p.apply_async(worker,
                      args=(path, i * chunksize, chunksize),
                      callback=progress_reporter)
    if leftover:
        p.apply_async(worker,
                      args=(path, full * chunksize, leftover),
                      callback=progress_reporter)
    p.close()
    p.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parallel_chunk(YOUR_FILE_PATH, YOUR_CHUNK_SIZE)
```

That requires no extra disk space and only enough extra RAM to create `ncpus` worker processes.  Provided the file size divided by `chunksize` is at least as large as `ncpus`, all `ncpus` worker processes will run simultaneously.  The amount of inter-process communication is trivial:  just a string (file path) and a few integers per chunk.

But there's no guarantee it will be faster than running on a single CPU.  That depends on countless details of how your OS, C libraries, and disk(s) interact, and on the details of what your processing function does.

Possible problem:  if the file size divided by `chunksize` is large, the multiprocessing machinery may indeed consume a correspondingly large amount of RAM in its internal queues to remember all the pending tasks (they're *all* fired off very quickly by the `apply_async()` calls - nothing here blocks waiting for results until we get to `p.join()`).  If that's a problem, the code needs to get more complicated to deal with it.  I'd simply increase `chunksize`.  But then all the workers could need more RAM (to deal with the larger `chunksize` - but whether that obtains depends on what `your_func()` does, and you haven't shown that).

Have fun :-)

Comment: well, there is a os.path.exists() method when we simple can try to open the file and thus determine if it exists. There's 'mincemeat' map-reduce Python framework, really simple and lightweight... why bother writing such a framework if we can use Python's map & reduce functions? =) I've been looking for a library or tool for such file-processing cases. I don't believe the world is divided by only 2 groups, 1st uses slow but simple 1-processor method, and 2nd uses complicated map-reduce approach. Well, thanks for the code, though I don't agree with your sarcasm =)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following you. What objection(s) do you have to the approach I showed? It uses all the processors you can throw at it, and requires nothing but Python's standard libraries. But it's so simple nobody is going to bother writing a library to encapsulate the pattern. In what way(s) does it fail to address your problem?

Comment: Your code is good and it's probably what I need for _this_ situation. But I was wandering if there's a library for some other, but similar, situations. What if we have a lot or RAM but slow HDD? What if we're limited in RAM but have a fast HDD (raid or SSD)? File processing is a very common task if you deal with data. Today I need  it to be done in this environment, tomorrow - in another. So it would be great to find a simple but flexible solution covering all these situations in different environments.

Comment: Well, it *can't* be "simple" if it has to optimize across the universe of possible storage media. For example, industrial strength relational databases devote person-centuries of programming effort to optimizing that kind of thing. To answer directly, I don't know of any such general-purpose library. If you want to make progress, it would be best to put a lot more effort into defining both the class of problems you hope to solve, and exactly what "different environments" consists of  and how to specify the relevant characteristics. "File processing" and "a lot of" (etc) are just too vague.